# return post data on server side validation failure

Tags: php, server-side-validation

I have a large registration form and if a user makes any mistake and failed on server side validation then how could I show up the fields which were previously correct.

How can I send the `post` data back to the registration form?

Comment: How does the server respond to an invalid form? What exactly is returned? Is the validation happening on submitting the form or are you sending the data via AJAX?

Comment: no I'm not using any `ajax`. The form is just submitted using `post` request. snippet: `<form action='val.php' method='post'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the `POST` values in session on your action page. In your `html` check if session value exists and then echo that. Expire the session once you are clear with server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are submitting the value of `myvalue2` without filling the value of `myvalue1` it will you an error with the posted data back

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if($_POST['myvalue1'])
   {
     $erromsg;
   }
}    

<input size="10" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['myvalue1']; ?> name="camp_click_value" id="xyz" />
<input size="10" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['myvalue2']; ?> name="camp_click_value" id="xyz" />
```